# "Would rather" in narrative past

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect

Let's say that we have a sentence like:

> He would rather the door didn't open.

Which means that he has a preference that the door wouldn't open. How can we express it in the past? - That he preferred (in the past) that the door didn't open (in the past).

[Here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/would-rather-would-sooner) we can find information that if we want to talk about a past preference we should use "rather have" like "I'd rather have done that", and if we want to talk about preference for different subject in the past we should use Past Perfect like "I'd rather you hadn't done that".

But what should we do when we want to talk about past preference for a different subject (like in a book - narrative tenses)?

Should it be:

1. He would rather have the door didn't open.
2. He would rather have the door hadn't opened.

?

Comment: 'Would rather' is a semi-modal that doesn't inflect for tense. You're going to have to give a past timeframe indication (if it's really necessary) by rephrasing. 'He hoped that the door wouldn't open' / 'He hoped that they would find it impossible to open the door'. Although I've seen say 'He was worried. He would rather the door would not be openable'.

Comment: You've forced yourself into a corner there. Maybe he *preferred* a closed door, and he *would have preferred* is okay. But he *would have rather* is a scary start for a sentence.

Comment: An intriguing question. I'm not going to answer with authority that there is no past-tense version, but I can say that bringing "have" into it doesn't fix it (and if you did, you'd need to get rid of the later verb). Personally I'd dodge the whole issue with a different wording like Edwin's.

Comment: Oh, ok. I'm asking only because I came across it in the book. "If the door really knew what he was thinking, he would have rather it didn’t open at all, but it did indeed give way to reveal the drawing room." Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Well, that's a... striking bit of speculative anthropomorphism. What on earth is it from?

Comment: Overlord Vol. 6 - a fantasy light novel. Maybe this sentence is a result of translation from Japanese to English.

Comment: Ah, looks like [Overlord vol 6 (light novel)](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Overlord_Vol_6_light_novel/acYrDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0), part of a manga franchise? And written by a Japanese author—perhaps also translated from Japanese? It's not a context that holds itself to extreme formality of usage, and I wouldn't put too much weight on any non-standard construction you find.

Comment: Note that 'He would have rather not been around when the door opened' refers to a dashed wish.

Comment: Yes, that's the book. It was translated by Emily Balistrieri. From what I can find it looks like he is not a native English speaker, so that could be the reason (not to put any shade on him, I think that he did a fantastic job overall).

Comment: Moral: don't ask grammar questions about stuff you read. Grammar is (a) about speech, not writing, and (b) not always correctly translated by non-native speakers. Unless you're asking about native speech, you're at one remove from the subject.

Comment: The problem is that in the two-word verbal idiom "would rather", it is just "would" that is a verb, with "rather" an adverb modifying it. Recasting to reflect past time is tricky, though perhaps "He would have rather that the door didn't open" may be acceptable to some speakers.

Comment: So just to be sure. "He preferred/hoped the door hadn't opened" is correct?